# Facebook OAuth2 without business verification

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth-2.0

Can an individual developer utilize Facebook OAuth for obtaining user emails? Is there a legitimate way to achieve this without business verification, i.e., without having a company? Based on e-mail I recognize user if he is already signed up using different identity provider such as Google.

Comment: From what I can see, this is not possible anymore without having a legit business with ein etc. But I am also interested in implementing this if possible. I have an older site which still works, but isn't a verified business.

Comment: @ToddHorst, as far as I know old sites will be also verified in the future. It is matter of time unfortunately.